# 403 error on google groups api in admin sdk, directory api

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, google-directory-api, google-groups

I am trying to get a list of google groups in my domain but getting: error 403 "Not Authorized to access this resource/api".

What am I doing wrong?

This is the node.js code I used:

```
    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const path = require('path');

    async function runSample() {
        const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: path.join(__dirname, 'service-account-super-admin.json'),
        scopes: [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member',
          'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
        ],
      });

     const admin = google.admin({
       version: 'directory_v1',
       auth,
      });

     let res
          res = await admin.groups.list({ domain: "mydomain.com" });
      }
      runSample().catch(console.error);
```

Thanks in advance